Realizing integer character as a group of integer matrices, and the natural generalization to ring generated by character values
A representation is realizable over the field generated by its character values iff the character has Schur index $ 1 $. For example the degree $ 2 $ character of the quaternion group $ Q_8 $ is integer valued but has Schur index $ 2 $ and is not realizable over $ \mathbb{Q} $.
What about the ring generated by the character values? Is it true that a representation is realizable over the ring generated by its character values iff the character has Schur index $ 1 $?
By the result above we certainly have that a representation is not realizable over the ring generated by its character values if the Schur index is not $ 1 $. But what if the Schur index is $ 1 $? Can we always realize the representation over the ring generated by its character values? It seems true for $ S_3 $ and $ S_4 $. But I assume it fails in general?
I'm not sure how you would find some character with Schur index $ 1 $ and prove that the representation cannot be realized over the ring generated by the character values? I guess the method of proof that $ Q_8 $ cannot be realized over $ \mathbb{Q} $ is that the rational algebra generated by the image of the representation is a division algebra and thus cannot be $ M_2(\mathbb{Q}) $. So maybe a proof could be done using some property of the $ \mathbb{Z} $-algebra generated by the image of the representation?
My intuition is that this is not true, so I am really looking for a counterexample, for example a integer valued character with Schur index $ 1 $ where the representation cannot be realized in the group of units of $ M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ where $ n $ is the degree of the character.
Update: Ah ok I did some more digging and it turns out that no integer valued character can be a counter example because of this result https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_is_realizable_over_principal_ideal_domain_iff_it_is_realizable_over_field_of_fractions
so to find a counterexample we would need a character whose values generated a domain with non-principal ideals. So we would need something like a $ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] $ or $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}] $ that is not a PID (granted this is true for most values of $ n $, just not the small values). For example $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] $ and $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] $ are not PIDs. $ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n] $ is bit rough because the first example that is not a PID is $ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}] $. So I would imagine a counterexample using a character whose values generate a ring like $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] $ and $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] $ is the way to go ($ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] $ doesn't work because that is a ED and thus a PID).
In conclusion, the easiest counterexample will probably have character values generating $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] $ or $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] $. It might not be the easiest but I bet the 11d and 12d irreps of $ SL(2,23) $ works as a counterexample, because they are over $ \sqrt{-23} $.

This seems unlikely to me. There are groups that have representations over a number field $K$ but cannot be represented over the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, so certainly not over the ring generated by character values. And I think you can arrange that $K$ is generated by the character values. When I have some time tonight, I'll try and cook up a specific example.
